# Can I replace / recreate a tri-fold garage door with three fiberglass flush doors?

Tags: doors, garage, exterior

My garage has three wooden doors that cover the opening.  The middle one's hinges are attached to the right door.  The left and the right doors' hinges are attached to the walls.  This way you could open only the middle door or two doors or all three doors to fully open it.

I know this is an odd setup but I actually kinda like it.

The garage is small and barely fits one car.  I don't use it for a garage but rather to store my tools and use it as a workshop.

The question:

The doors need to be replaced.  I looked at standard garage doors but didn't like them very much.  I'm going in and out of the garage pretty often, especially these days when I'm renovating.  I'm a bike commuter so get in and out with my bike at least twice a day.

I'm toying with the idea of redoing it the same way (with three doors) but use three modern fiberglass flush doors or maybe even doors with half windows.

Would this work?  Or it a bad idea?

Comment: it depends, do you have access to "pre-fab fiberglass three part garage door" parts, or are you doing some cutting?

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of purchasing three fiberglass exterior doors without the frames (at < $200 each) and putting everything together.  Does it make sense?

Comment: @PeterQ - how did you go with this? If you installed them you could always add an answer here listing the pros and cons.

Comment: What are the width and height dimensional measurements of this space that you are replacing doors in?  Could you possibly replace them with a double door setup (eg. to fill a 7' opening a 36" & 48" doors). This would reduce the fatigue cause by the three door setup of the middle door attached to whichever side door and extend the life of the system.

Answer (score 1):

If the existing setup works, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work with new doors instead. One down side to this setup though, is that doors without jambs aren't that secure and could probably be kicked in fairly easily. If it were my garage, and I didn't want a standard fold up door or a roll-up, I'd probably put in 2 larger barn style doors, or if you have the space, one of those sliding barn style doors that has an overhead track to slide on.